# Transfer Virtualbox Linux distro to physical machine - Shutdown / reboot problems

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, virtualbox, laptop, acpi

Maybe it serves to describe my current situation first:

- installed ubuntu on virtualbox (btrfs)
- created btrfs partition on my laptop
- booted on a live distro, used btrfs send/receive to transfer the root subvolume from the virtualbox
- set up grub so I can now boot my laptop from the ubuntu subvolume

The **problem** that arises: I can boot ubuntu, but I **cannot reboot or shutdown** the system. Whenever I click shutdown, or issue a 'shutdown now' command, the system freezes completely. I have a feeling that this is because ACPI is not installed, but I'm in doubt why this could be. Does the ubuntu installation detect that virtualbox does not need ACPI, so it does not add it? I have verified that no acpi service is running in the distro.

I have done this for an ubuntu 16.04 and an arch installation, both with the same conclusion / problem. My question is: is this really because of ACPI? Am I missing some other functionality due to this transfer of virtual to physical? Is the problem solved by simply installing ACPI packages in ubuntu / arch?

Comment: Have you checked dmesg from the previous boot?

Comment: there _were_ some references in dmesg to ACPI. A number of  errors:

    [    0.037510] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/dswload-210)
    [    0.037517] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170531/psobject-252)
    [    0.037556] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rvp11) while loading table (20170531/tbxfload-228)
    [    0.040342] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 12 successful (20170531/tbxfload-246

some additional output, references to the power button/battery/... and then a number of loaded modules

Comment: In the arch subinstallation: installed `acpid` and `gnome`. Now the system shuts down, I guess it's due to the acpid service being active. Still it's strange to me that the installation would hand pick the ACPI service as something unnecessary in the virtualbox install?

Comment: however, in ubuntu, after making sure acpid is enabled and running, a `reboot` command will instantly lock up the machine. So I guess something else is still going on...

Comment: As for the success in arch: the installation of `gnome` had nothing to do with it. I retried, after installing gnome+gnome-extra the system didn't reboot either. After a hard reboot, installed `acpid`, enabled / started the service. Then did `reboot`, the system hangs again.

Answer (score 0):

The hard lock @reboot or @shutdown time was apparently caused by the graphics drivers of my laptop not yet being loaded. Installing the drivers fixed the problem. Hopefully someone is helped by this, avoiding some sidetrack time on the ACPI path.